# Protecting wealth when stock is in bankruptcy

Tags: stocks

Earlier this year, I put a large percentage of my wealth into JC Penney Company stock.  It was a huge gamble, and I ended up losing big time as the company is now in Chapter 11 Bankruptcy.  I haven't yet sold any of my shares.

I just got a mailing that says "Notice of non-voting status to holders of impaired claims conclusively deemed to reject the plan and notice of option to opt out of third-party releases".  I tried reading through it, but it's very heavy on the legal terminology and I don't really understand it.  I have the option of signing it.

I'm not going to ask if I should sign it.  But I do want to know, would signing/not signing this make any difference in protecting my wealth at all?  Is this something a lawyer would be able to help with?

Comment: Contact JC Penney Investor relations (Google for the phone number).  Call any phone numbers on the papers that you received or E-mail if that was provided.  Perhaps you'll find someone who can explain the situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you should be thinking in terms of "_protecting my wealth_", but "_salvaging anything if I can_". However, as [this Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/walterloeb/2020/10/22/jcpenney-reorganization-plan-wipes-out-shareholders/), written towards the end of October, says it "_seems clear_" that shareholders will "_get no monetary recovery and their stock is cancelled_", it may well be there is little to salvage.

Comment: [This article](https://www.dlapiper.com/en/us/insights/publications/2020/10/restructuring-global-insight/third-party-releases/) touches on "_third-party releases_" (in Delaware). I don't know enough on the subject to write an answer, but skimming it _suggests_ the execution of a rescue plan can hinge on whether the buyers are released from potential claims from third-parties (which I assume includes shareholders): without releases the plan _might_ not go ahead. If the plan goes ahead, then from my first link it seems shareholders get nothing. [**cont**]

Comment: [**cont**] The question then seems to be: will they get anything if the plan _doesn't_ go ahead, to which I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: @TripeHound thanks a lot!  I don't know if it makes a difference, but I own 136 shares.

Comment: I'm not following. JCP hasn't been above $2 a share since 2018. "A large percentage of your wealth" this year was 136 shares?

Comment: @spuck you can come out and say it: I'm poor. I know that I'm poor and I know that this recent gamble didn't help with that. I would love to have more money to be able to save and invest, but finances are VERY tight. Not all of us are in the 1%, and we're just trying our best with the little bit we have.

Comment: @Jor70 I apologize if my comment is in poor taste, and I mean no disrespect; I understand wealth is a relative term. Your question was if signing or not signing made any difference or if a lawyer might be able to help. Unless you have a friend or relative who is a lawyer that might give you an opinion for free, do not expect a lawyer to help for the amount of money involved, and it would be throwing good money after bad to go into debt to figure this out. Best I can offer is to count this as an expensive lesson in gambling. Sorry!

Comment: @Jor70 your question was misleading. words like 'protecting wealth' don't go together with $200 in ANY country, least of all the US where the average wage is around $50,000 per year. Your question is very different from if you had invested $200,000, which is what I would have guessed from reading it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Charles E. Grant mentioned in a comment, JCP has been delisted and is currently trading for 11 cents per share.  There's no preserving your wealth.  For this investment, at this point, it's gone.

I just read an article in my local newspaper that says that the US Bankruptcy Court for the Southern District of Texas approved the sale of the company to its two largest landlords and its primary lenders.

With no other offers in sight, this financing agreement expires November 20th.  If that happens, JC Penney will go out of business.  And even with acceptance, they're going to close nearly 1/3 of their stores as they restructure.  It's going to be a long hard slog for Penneys to recover, even more so because of the pandemic.

My guess is that the papers you received are a vote for or against the sale.  However, you shouldn't take my word for it.  See if there's some language referring to sale of assets to Brookfield Asset Management and Simon Property Group.

Answer (score -3):

You should sign it. As a shareholder of a company, even if it's in bankruptcy and even if it's not really a vote, your voice should be heard by some body and is the fundamental blocks of being a part of the community.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I'm really more interested in preserving my wealth than making my voice heard.  The more I think about it, the more I'm thinking I should really consider hiring a lawyer.

Comment: @Jor70 J.C. Penny stock is currently at $.11/share. Your entire 136 share are unfortunately worth less than $15. Most lawyers will offer a free initial consultation, but if they actually started doing work for you they would charge hundreds of dollars per hour. I suspect any ethical lawyer is going to explain to you that costs of a consultation would simply drive you into debt. Sadly you need to resign yourself to the fact that your investment is gone, whether or not you sign the paper.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant thanks a lot for the feedback; that really helps.